# glBufferSubData 1281 error

Tags: java, debugging, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to get instanced rendering working, but I can't seem to find the reason why my glBufferSubData gives me an 1281 exception (Invalid value).

Here is my code:

```
FloatBuffer square_vertices_fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
     square_vertices_fb.put(square_vertices);
     square_vertices_fb.rewind();

     FloatBuffer instance_colors_fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(instance_colors.length);
     instance_colors_fb.put(instance_colors);
     instance_colors_fb.rewind();

     FloatBuffer instance_positions_fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(instance_positions.length);
     instance_positions_fb.put(instance_positions);
     instance_positions_fb.rewind();
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, square_vertices.length + instance_colors.length + instance_positions.length, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(glGetError()));
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, square_vertices_fb);
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(glGetError()));
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, square_vertices.length, instance_colors_fb);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, square_vertices.length + instance_colors.length, instance_positions_fb);
```

I get 0 (no error) at the first error check, but an 1281 error just after the first glBufferSubData.

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I found out that LWJGL's glBufferSubData wants the offset in bytes. Problem is fixed.